# Floating action button makes the list view laggy

Tags: android, listview, scroll, lag, floating-action-button

I have a customized list view working fine, but when I added a floating action button, scrolling became very laggy
And when I remove it it scrolls fast again

What should I do to keep the floating action button without lag on scroll

Comment: I'm assuming here that you bind each item view properly within a view holder, correct? Some code snippets here would be useful btw

Comment: Yeah I'm using view holder you're goddamn right :-),

Comment: But what should I do

Comment: Well for starters, include some relevant code snippets into your post, particularly the ListView's adapter and the list item's layout